# How do I use xpath predicates to exclude all nodes except those that meet a condition?

Tags: .net, xml, xpath, predicate

I need help using xpath to exclude particular nodes from an xml node list. The xml structure is below. The xml file is large, around 8000 items, the majority of which are submenu type.

```
<Menu>
  <MenuId>2905</MenuId> 
  <Item>
     <ItemId>191916</ItemId>
     <ItemType>content</ItemType> 
  </Item>
  <Item>
     <ItemId>17343</ItemId>
     <ItemType>submenu</ItemType>
     <Menu>
         ...
     </Menu>
  </Item>
</Menu>
```

What I need to do is for a certain MenuID (2905, for example) exclude all child nodes except those where ItemType = 'content'

I thought the below would work?

```
Menu[MenuId !='2905' or MenuId = '2905' and child::ItemType = 'content']/Item
```

Shouldn't that select all nodes that are not in 2905 and any that are in 2905 and of the content type? The .NET usage I've tried is below:

```
        XmlNodeList nextLevelNodeList = currentNode.SelectNodes(string.Format("Menu[MenuId !='2905' or MenuId = '2905' and child::ItemType = 'content']/Item));
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated...

cheers
Nathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Both previous answers are incorrect**.

**Use** (from the parent of the `Menu` elements):

```
 Menu[not(MenuId = 2905)]/Item
|
 Menu[MenuId = 2905]/Item[ItemType='content']
```

Comment: Hi @Dimitre 
This will work, but I'm unsure how to translate the expression into my NodeList definition

        XmlNodeList nextLevelNodeList = currentNode.SelectNodes(string.Format("Menu/Item[ItemLevel={0}]", iLevel));

I can't use an or operator in string.format, can i?

Comment: @Nathan: Of course you can -- it is part of the string:  `string.Format("Menu[not(MenuId = {0}) | Menu[MenuId = {0}]/Item[ItemType='content']]", iLevel)`  BTW this is not "or" but the union operator.

Comment: Nice, works great. To further complicate it, could I store a series of MenuIds in an array, and use that within string.Format? Like the pseudocode below...
    int[] menuIdArray = {2905, 323, 43453};
    Menu[not(MenuId in MenuIdArray)

Thinking it would be wise to future-proof the menus to allow the solution to be applied across multiple menus

Comment: Yes, in XSLT this can be done. Also in XPath 2.0. Please, ask a new, separate question

Answer (score 3):

Adding one to the list of XPath expressions, without node set union:

```
//Menu/Item[../MenuId != 2905 or ItemType = 'content']
```

Meaning: *from any `Menu` element, the `Item` child having a sibling `MenuId` not equal to `2905` or a `ItemType` child equal to `'content'`*

Answer (score 1):

Combine two node lists:

```
Menu[MenuId != '2905']/Item
```

And

```
Menu[MenuId = '2905']/Item[ItemType = 'content']
```